# OpenShift: How can I find the driver-toolkit image for a given OpenShift version through the REST API in an operator pod?

Tags: openshift

On the command line, you can look-up the driver-tookit image for a given OpenShift version using:

`oc adm release info 4.11.45 --image-for=driver-toolkit`

How do you do the same look-up through the REST API inside of an operator pod?

I tried a GET on:
`api.openshift.com/api/upgrades_info/v1/graph?channel=stable-4.11&arch=amd64&version=4.11.45`

this returned a lot of output, but nothing about driver-toolkit.

Linear searching through a list like this would be OK (if it contained driver-toolkit image), but it would be nicer if there were a more direct way to search for the component directly.